# Why is loss function giving "nan" value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression, loss-function

I was trying to implement logistic regression using pytorch but the output of loss function is "nan"? How can I solve it?

**Data loading and manupulation**

```py
dataLoad=load_breast_cancer()
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(dataLoad.data,dataLoad.target,test_size=0.33)
scaler=StandardScaler()
X_train=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=scaler.transform(X_test)
X_train=X_train.transpose()
Y_train=Y_train.transpose()
inputX=th.from_numpy(X_train.astype(np.float32))
outputY=th.from_numpy(Y_train.astype(np.float32))
```

**This is loss function and model**

```py
def lossFunction(predictY,outputY):
  loss= (outputY*(th.log(predictY))+(1-outputY)*(th.log((1-predictY)))).sum()*-1/381
  return loss
def modelFunction(inputX,a,b):
  linear=a.mm(inputX)+b;
  sigmoidfun=th.nn.Sigmoid()
  sigmoidValue=sigmoidfun(linear)
  return sigmoidValue
```

**This is training loop**

```py
a=th.randn((1,30),requires_grad=True)
b=th.randn(1,requires_grad=True)
epoch=1000
optimizer=th.optim.Adam([a,b],lr=0.1)

losses=[]
for i in range(epoch):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  predict=modelFunction(inputX,a,b)
  loss=lossFunction(predict,outputY)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
  losses.append(loss.item())
```

Comment: Either `predict` or `outputY` is probably a NaN, did you check those? If you check for NaNs in the training loop, you can get the value of `i` when you fail and see which example is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the sigmoid as your activation function. mean your output (predictions) could be 0 and log of that will be -Inf, in your loss function add epsilon for stability purposes.

```
log(x) -> replace with log(x + eps) // eps= 1e-7 (somehting small)
```

if you use the builtin loss functions there are many checks and guards to prevent from such problems. But I would imagine this is some excercise which you want to see how the loss is calculated.